# Logstash Beats Input - multiple multiline codec

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to send multiple types of logs with beats and parse them on the logstash server.

I have beats configured and working properly and almost have logstash working correctly.

Where I am having issues is that other-log.log has entries that start with a different format string.

In an ideal world I would like to be able to apply a different `multiline` codec depending on the `type` of entry.

I have tried

```
if [type] == "server.log" {
    codec => multiline {
        pattern => "^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+"
        negate => true
        what => "previous"
    }
}
```

However that causes logstash to fail, my guess is that `if` is not allowed in the `input` block.

I have also tried to use the `multiline` filter plugin but it results in

> "Couldn't find any filter plugin named 'multiline'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the multiline filter plugin resulted in this error: LoadError"

Does anyone have an idea as to how to make this work?

**filebeat.yml**

```
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /application/server.log
  document_type: server.log
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /tmp/other-log.log
  document_type: other.log
```

**pipeline.conf**

```
input {
    beats {
        host => "0.0.0.0"
        port => "5044"
        codec => multiline {
                pattern => "^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+"
                negate => true
                what => "previous"
        }
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "server.log" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "(?<date>^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)\s(?<level>[A-Z]+)\s+\[(?<class>.*?)\]\s+(?<message>(?m).*)" }
            overwrite => ["message"]
            add_tag =>  [ "server.log" ]
        }
    }
}
# The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is
# optional.
# filter {
#
# }
output {
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I moved the multiline to `filebeat.yml` and that solved my issues :)

Comment: how can you configure multiple multiline patterns in `filebeat.yml` ?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration for moving multiline to filebeat.yaml is here. I captured multiline logs using the following configuration.
This is my filebeat.yaml configuration:

```
# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================
 filebeat.inputs:
    - type: log
      enabled: true
      paths:
        - /var/log/nginx/access.log
        - /var/log/nginx/error.log
      multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]' // these
      multiline.negate: false           // three
      multiline.match: after            // lines are important for capturing multiline logs
------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
  index: "my-index-name"
```

You can also take reference from [this blog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html)